# Form with list not POSTing

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a form for a model containing some standard input fields and a list of files. The user is supposed to choose the files that should be linked to the model via checkbox.

The form for that model POSTs perfectly fine as long as this list of files is not included. The moment it is, however, and I click the submit button, the page keeps reloading.

Here the relevant code. Please be aware that the examples are reduced significantly.

### Form in .cshtml

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label asp-for="Description"></label>
        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" type="text" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Description"></span>
    </div>
    @if (Model.Files.Any())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            <input asp-for="@Model.Files[i].Id" type="hidden" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="@Model.Files[i].Link" type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
            @Model.Files[i].Description
        }
    }
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

### Action in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Model model)
{
    // saving to DB, additional validation, etc
    return View(model);
}
```

### HTML

```
<form action="Edit" method="post">            
    <input id="Id" type="hidden" name="Id" value="43" />
    <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="Description">Description</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter description." id="Description" name="Description" value="Test" />
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Description" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="Files_0__Id" name="Files[0].Id" value="29" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Link field is required." id="Files_0__Link" name="Files[0].Link" value="true" />
    </div>
    111.png
    <input type="hidden" id="Files_1__Id" name="Files[1].Id" value="30" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Link field is required." id="Files_1__Link" name="Files[1].Link" value="true" />
    </div>
    222.png
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="[...]" />
    <input name="Files[0].Link" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <input name="Files[1].Link" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

### Models

```
public class Model
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description.")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<FileModel> Files { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class FileModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public long? Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Link")]
    public bool Link { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to use a standard multi select as I will display a thumbnail showing the file contents next to each option.

My end goal here is to post the list of chosen files together with the rest of the form, so linking each file separately through Ajax or something similar is out. The form is supposed to work with a new object that has not yet been added to the database and thus does not have an ID yet.

I am however open to other ideas, especially if there is some idiomatic .net core way I am not aware of yet.

Comment: If it's not POSTing then it sounds like it's not matching the route, what does your POST action look like?

Comment: I added a pared down version of the controller method to the question. The thing is, as soon as I comment out the for loop, it POSTs just fine.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a malformed HTML problem, I would suggest inspecting the page once it's loaded (with files) and checking for errors or pasting the `<form>` block here and we can have a look. If HTML is badly formed then submitting sometimes just reloads the page. I suspect the input tags are missing something important or have errors in them.

Comment: Added the HTML. The only thing that (to me) appears weird is the two hidden inputs right at the bottom, below the verification token. Then again, I am not that well-versed in HTML.

Comment: Maybe a problem in the bindings? Can we see the model posted?

Comment: How come the button isn't inside your form? Did you remove it?

Comment: @NibblyPig You are right, I accidentally removed it along a bunch of Bootstrap divs :) 
 Added back in. I took all the styling etc out as it's just a bunch of clutter.

Comment: If you open the network inspector when you press the submit button, is it doing a GET or a POST? If the page is refreshing I still think it's something in the markup, and it has nothing to do with MVC model binding. Keep in mind doing `return View(model);` will simply reload the page. If you breakpoint your action method does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: Sadly I cannot check the network inspector right now as I am not at work anymore, but the breakpoint is hit when the for loop is commented out, but not when it is left in.

It never reaches the `return View(model)`, that is only for when validation or the DB operation fails anyway. It's POSTing back to the controller at all that's the problem.

Comment: I tried your code without any problem.However, I see your html has`<form action="Edit" method="post"> ` while it might be  `action="controller/action` (in my demo it is `action="/Models/Edit`) ,so maybe the url is incorrect which leads to your posting failure?

Comment: @NibblyPig Checked out the network inspector, it just says the status of the request is pending. The url looks fine though. 
As I said before, the moment I comment out the for loop it POSTs, so I don't see how it could be a problem with the url.